# Can the following integral involving digamma be evaluated in closed form (special functions allowed but not preferred)?

Tags: definite-integrals, digamma-function, q-analogs

$$\int_1^n \frac {\psi(x)}{x} dx \ s.t. \ n \in \mathbb N$$

EDIT: I've relocated the asking about the integral of the above except with the q-analog of the digamma to another question. This is so as to avoid cluttering this question and keeping it focused on a single task that was already answered.

Comment: To integrate a special function and not to get something related to values of a special function is very optimistic, sometimes too much.

Comment: special functions are okay, I just want something computationally efficient is all.  I don't want the number of terms growing with the input in some divergent way or something crazy like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{dx}{g(x)}$ tell us very little about $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,dx$, so I do not really get the actual meaning of the premises. Anyway, the digamma function $\psi$ can be defined through
$$ \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{(m+a)(m+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b},\qquad \psi(1)=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\log n-H_n\right)=-\gamma. $$
In particular you are asking for an explicit evaluation of

$$ -\gamma\log(n)-1+\frac{1}{n}+\color{blue}{\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{1}{m}\log\left(\frac{m+n}{m+1}\right)}$$
or
$$ -\gamma\log(n)-1+\frac{1}{n}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}(e^{-nx}-e^{-x})\log(1-e^{-x})\frac{dx}{x}$$
or
$$ -\gamma\log(n)-1+\frac{1}{n}+\int_{0}^{1}(1-u^{n-1})\frac{\log(1-u)}{\log u}\,du.$$
This is numerically pretty simple, but I doubt there is an elementary expression for the given integral, if we exclude series involving values of the $\zeta$ function or [Stieltjes constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants). If we employ the Euler-Maclaurin summation method, the first term of the approximation of the blue series is
$$\begin{eqnarray*}&&\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\log\left(\frac{m+n}{m+1}\right)\frac{dm}{m}\\&=&\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(n)+\text{Li}_2\left(-\tfrac{1}{n}\right).\end{eqnarray*} $$
Of course the dominant term for large values of $n$ is $\frac{1}{2}\log^2(n)$.

Comment: I see, does this same argument apply for the q-analog of the digamma function?  I am interested in the similar integral above but for the q-digamma instead of just the digamma, as well.

Comment: Also, what is the error bound on the first term of the approximation of the blue term?

Comment: Thank you, by the way!

Comment: I doubt this technique can be applied to the $q$-analog without some major reworking, and I wonder what is the actual purpose of computing $\int \psi_q(x)\frac{dx}{x}$, too. Anyway, putting together the explicit terms mentioned in my answer we get an approximation within $O\left(\log n\right)$ from the actual value (assuming that $n$ is large).

Comment: To be completely honest, I received this question in the final answer of [another question I'd already asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321583/what-partial-sum-formulae-exist-for-this-basic-hypergeometric-series/321777#321777). Since I was having a bit of trouble understanding that answer, I asked another one here.  I probably should have asked about the q-analog first, but I needed to even know if it first even made sense to talk about the integral without q-analogs.